# Tex figures only work in Pandoc with a Markdown image first

Tags: graphics, errors, pandoc

I use Pandoc's markdown to generate a PDF file. To have more control over figures and images I use inline latex like the following:

```
## Chapter 12

\begin{figure}[htbp]\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, height=!]{images/castle01.png}\centering\end{figure}

lorem ipsum
```

This produces following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.80 \begin{figure}[htbp]\includegraphics
```

But if I use a markdown image once before, the image is rendered.

```
## Chapter 12

![](castle01.png){width=50%}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, height=!]{images/castle01.png}\centering\end{figure}

lorem ipsum
```

I assume this is some kind of initialization issue that only occurs once for the first image. How can I use the latex way without once Markdown image?

Comment: You have to load the `graphicx` package (sorry, I don't know how that's done in pandoc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [YAML metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks) to enable graphics/graphicx like this:

```
---
graphics: yes
---
## Chapter 12

\begin{figure}[htbp]\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, height=!]{images/castle01.png}\centering\end{figure}

lorem ipsum
```